# php - Get all static objects together (Call static)

Tags: php, laravel, class, oop, url-routing

I need some advice to sove the problem.

So, It's hard to exaplay what I want to. By the reason I'm gonna show you what I want to:

**I have this:**

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController::index')->name('index');
Route::get('/news', 'NewsController::News')->name('news');
```

**Instead of**

```
$routes = new Route();
$routes->get('/', 'IndexController::index')->name('index');
$routes->get('/news', 'NewsController::News')->name('news');
```

**And I need to get the objects like this:**

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController::index')->name('index');
Route::get('/news', 'NewsController::News')->name('news');
Route::get('/about', 'AboutController::About')->name('about');

$getTheObject = Route::getWholeObject();

echo'<pre>';
print_r($getTheObject);
echo'</pre>';
```

**If I try to get the whole router object as I need But it returns an object with empty routes array:**

```
Core\Router\Router Object
(
    [routes] => Array
        (
            [names] => Array
                (
                )

            [paths] => Array
                (
                )

            [params] => Array
                (
                )
        )

    [uri] => /rfrfrfr
    [KeepPermamentPath] => 
)
```

**If I try like this it returns the correct object but I don't want to write it that ugly way ($routes->etc...) :**

```
$routes = new Route();
$routes->get('/', 'IndexController::index')->name('index');
$routes->get('/news', 'NewsController::News')->name('news');

echo'<pre>';
print_r($routes);
echo'</pre>';
```

The object

```
Core\Router\Router Object
(
    [routes] => Array
        (
            [names] => Array
                (
                    [index] => Array
                        (
                            [path] => /
                            [call] => IndexController::index
                            [methods] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => get
                                )

                            [name] => index
                        )

                    [news] => Array
                        (
                            [path] => /news
                            [call] => NewsController::News
                            [methods] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => get
                                )

                            [name] => news
                        )

                )

            [paths] => Array
                (
                    [/] => Array
                        (
                            [path] => /
                            [call] => IndexController::index
                            [methods] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => get
                                )

                            [name] => index
                        )

                    [/news] => Array
                        (
                            [path] => /news
                            [call] => NewsController::News
                            [methods] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => get
                                )

                            [name] => news
                        )

                )

            [params] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [uri] => /rfrfrfr
    [KeepPermamentPath] => /news
)
```

Source on github: https://github.com/amirandev/php-better-router

[image]